# What is the equivalent of windirstat for Android for identifying space hogs

Tags: android, disk-space, disk-utility

I have a Google Nexus 6 running Android 7.1.1. How can I find what is occupying the device's disk space ? It has a 32 GB disk but most of the time, I see only 300-400 MB free space, getting constant warnings. After deleting bunch of photographs and deleting many apps, I got 2 GB free but I would like to know what is occupying the remaining disk space.

On windows, I run windirstat to get an understanding of the disk space usage. For my Android phone, I've tried previously to use Explorer to copy the various Android directories to my PC disk and then run windirstat. But that is time consuming and not practical.

Are there tools/processes which will allow me to find and cleanup space hogging files/directories on my Android phone ?

If there is a better forum to ask these questions, pls. point me.

Thanks much

Comment: I use this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alphainventor.filemanager&hl=en on top right, slect the 3 points and tap **analyze** hee it shows disk space usage

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did a google on this and found that there are multiple apps which do equivalent functionality. The one I ended up using was [diskusage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage&hl=en). This app needs a compatible file manager and suggests a few(freeware and payware).

I found that Whatsapp was consuming a huge chunk of my space. I could delete about 10 GB worth of Whatsapp videos.